# Indexing not supported?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7

I get this error message:

`TypeError: 'City' object does not support indexing`

when this is my model:

```
class City(db.Model):
  region = db.ReferenceProperty()
  name = db.StringProperty()
  image = db.BlobProperty()
  vieworder = db.IntegerProperty()
  areacode = db.IntegerProperty()
```

and this is my query

```
items = Item.all().filter('modified >', timeline).filter('published =',                 True).order('-modified').filter('cities =',city[0].key()).fetch(PAGESIZE + 1)`
```

Can you tell my how I should make my query or model my class definitions? I use `listproperty(db.Key)` to model relationships with references and I thought I could filter like the above query since it worked for one item. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
city[0].key()
```

is the cause of your error. Chances are you thought `city` was a list, but it's actually a single item, or some such.